# Solaris (SPARC) development environment

Tags: gcc, solaris, opensolaris

I'm working on a cross-platform application for which I would like to include Solaris/SPARC support but I no longer have access to a server. I have an OpenSolaris VM on VirtualBox but I don't know of any SPARC VM which I could use to compile and test on. Did I miss something? Otherwise, do you know of solaris/SPARC shell account services with the gcc toolchain, preferably free ones?

Comment: qemu offers SPARC computer simulation.

Comment: @osgx - I'm researching the same thing and was looking at qemu, but everything I've seen implies that it's not up to running a full Solaris SPARC install. Is this something you've had luck with?

Comment: @osgx thanks for you reply.
@Aron I'll try to install OpenSolaris SPARC on qemu next week. I'll let you know how it went.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160800/sparc-assembly). I haven't seen anything about Solaris running on qemu, otherwise you can get SPARC hosting for $10 at [polarhome](http://www.polarhome.com/).

Comment: I'll check polarhome out if I don't have luck with qemu. thanks

Comment: I ended up getting polarhome accounts for Solaris/SPARC and AIX. It took w while to get my application processed but the service lived up to my expectations. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free SPARC emulator from http://www.stromasys.ch/virtualization-solutions/virtual-sparcstation/.

Comment: Link is now http://www.stromasys.com/products/charon-freeware/charon-spkss20-freeware-download/